# iOS: Swift Constant File

Tags: ios, swift, struct, constants

Which is more efficient during runtime?

Constants.swift:

```
let CONSTANT1 = 2
let CONSTANT2 = 0.034
let CONSTANT_STRING = "String"
let CONSTANT_COLOR = UIColor.red
```

or

Constants.swift

```
struct Constants {
   static let CONSTANT1 = 2
   static let CONSTANT2 = 0.034
   static let CONSTANT_STRING = "String"
   static let CONSTANT_COLOR = UIColor.red
}
```

or is there a difference at all during runtime?

Comment: Did you measure any performance difference?

Comment: Test yourself: create a pair of loops, one to use each type of constant, that run a huge number of times. Set up a timer to see how long each loop takes to run. Print the time each took and compare.

Comment: And don't do any kind of performance test in a playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler optimization is sophisticated enough that it's extremely unlikely there will be any performance difference. The compiler can tell that they're all constants, so the compiled code will likely be identical or nearly so. You could try both ways and attempt to profile the difference (if any). It would almost certainly be a waste of time unless you're very interested in compilers.